# Migrate VMWare Workstation (free) virtual machine on vSphere

Tags: vmware-workstation, license, esxi, vsphere

I would like to know if it was possible to copy/migrate/export a virtual machine created with the free version of VMWare Workstation to the free version of vSphere Hypervisor (bare metal).

If it was possible, could someone explain me how?

I tried to search online, but all the posts I've found assume non-free version of Workstation.

If it wasn't possible, do I need Workstation Pro license or Player is enough?

Comment: There is no free version of VMWare Workstation. Do you mean VMWare Player, or perhaps the trial version of VMWare Workstation?

Comment: @harrymc From a couple of years, maybe more, VMWare calls both the products Workstation, there is a free Workstation Player, a payed (licensed) Workstation Player and a payed Workstation Pro. Anyway I mean free not licensed Workstation Player.

Answer (score 1):

You create a new VM in vSphere with same ressources and then just attach VMDK, as **John** mentioned.

Or to simplify the migration one of V2V converters can be used - http://www.vmwareblog.org/v2v-converters-overview/